# How to login with python and save cookie, then use that info to view page for member only

Tags: python

I am quite new in python and trying to write a script to login to the page at http://ryushare.com/login.python.

I have try many attempt, but it fails to login and i have no idea why.
After login to the page, I wish to get the return of http://ryushare.com/file-manager.python

Here's the code I try to attempt by reading the example from others.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.ryushare.com/login.python', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://ryushare.com/file-manager.python')
print resp.read()
```

I check the source code of the login page, it said the username and password value is "login and password" so i change it.
I have try some other example which can be found here like google news feed, It also can not able to login : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page's source, we have the following HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://ryushare.com/" name="FL">
```

You should be open()'ing the "action" page, e.g.

```
opener.open('http://ryushare.com/", login_data)
# Now you can interact with site
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp:

> Submit Button
>
> `<input type="submit" />` defines a submit button.
>
> A submit button is used to send form data to a server. **The data is
>   sent to the page specified in the form's action attribute.** The file
>   defined in the action attribute usually does something with the
>   received input:
>
> ```
> <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
> Username: <input type="text" name="user" /> <input type="submit"
> value="Submit" /> </form>
> ```
>
> How the HTML code above looks in a browser:
>
> Username: (Entry box)
>
> If you type some characters in the text field above, and
>   click the "Submit" button, the browser will send your input to a page
>   called "html_form_action.asp". The page will show you the received
>   input.

## Edit: Other Form Data

As can be seen in the comments, the OP still had trouble after applying this fix. The answer is that there are often hidden form  tags, including the  for the submit button. Include these tags' data in your request as well as your username and password.

Comment: I edit the code, but i still can't login. When i print the read(), it still ask me for the login data. It seem the cookie is not save or something.

Comment: Maybe try `{'login' : username, 'password' : password, 'loginFormSubmit' : 'Login', 'op' : 'login'}`. If that doesn't work, then I don't know.

Comment: Would you mind voting/besting the answer so I can at least get enough rep to comment on others' answers? Thx :P

Comment: I have one more question, in http://ryushare.com/files/FF7.AVI i try to use webbrowser with my membership, the link returns http://server1.ryushare.com/files/FF7.AVI and download straight away. when i try to open and do a response.read() it just freeze there...? all i want to get from the script is to know the address of http://server1.ryushare.com/files/FF7.AVI

Comment: I'm not quite sure, because when I go to those links nothing happens. I think you mean that when you go to the first link in a webbrowser, it automatically redirects you to the second download and starts downloading the file, correct?

And you're saying that you also get automatically redirected when you request it with Python? If these are both correct, then here's the answer:

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html  

`urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods: geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed`   
And of course, opener.open() is the same function. So instead if read(), do geturl().

Comment: I am really happy to get help from you. U have solved my problem and Finally my script is complete. Thank you